# I can't replace drop down values to string in flutter then send it to the database

Tags: php, flutter, dart, foreign-keys, dropdownbutton

I'm beginner flutter developer.
So in my project I used five Drop Down Button to insert data to the database all this week I can't resolve this problem[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCFUj.jpg)

this is my flutter code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:app/screen/CustomErrorScreen.dart';
import 'package:app/widgets/CustomTextField10.dart';
import 'package:app/widgets/CustomTextField11.dart';
import 'package:app/widgets/CustomTextField12.dart';
import 'package:app/widgets/CustomTextField7.dart';
import 'package:app/widgets/CustomTextField8.dart';
import 'package:app/widgets/CustomTextField9.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../login/SignUpPage.dart';
import '../screen/Color.dart';
import '../singup/SignInPage.dart';
import '../widgets/CustomTextField.dart';
import '../widgets/CustomTextField13.dart';
import '../widgets/GlassMorphismContainer.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

TextEditingController vc= TextEditingController();
TextEditingController ac= TextEditingController();
TextEditingController wh= TextEditingController();
TextEditingController cr= TextEditingController();
TextEditingController ad= TextEditingController();
TextEditingController dt= TextEditingController();
TextEditingController des= TextEditingController();
TextEditingController cus= TextEditingController();
TextEditingController cdel= TextEditingController();
var names = ['dooro mid'];
var names1 = ['dooro mid'];
var names2 = ['dooro mid'];
var names3 = ['dooro mid'];
var names4 = ['dooro mid'];
String text = "dooro mid";
String text1 = "dooro mid";
String text2 = "dooro mid";
String text3 = "dooro mid";
String text4 = "dooro mid";

var user="1";
bool bol = true;
bool bol1 = true;
bool bol2 = true;
bool bol3 = true;
bool bol4 = true;
class peoForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const peoForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _peoFormState createState() => _peoFormState();
}

class _peoFormState extends State<peoForm> {



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CustomErrorMessege();
    return Scaffold(
      //resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        // reverse: true,
        child: Container(
          width: Get.width,
          height: Get.height,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
           image: DecorationImage(
             image: AssetImage("images/pol.jpg"),
             fit: BoxFit.cover
           ),
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [
                  purpleBack,
                  blueBack,
                ],
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight
            ),
          ),
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned(
                    left: -50,
                    top: Get.height * 0.075,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 200,
                      width: 200,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                              colors: [Color(0xD789229C), circlePurpleDark]
                          )
                      ),
                    )
                ),
                Positioned(
                    right: -50,
                    bottom: Get.height * 0.075,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 200,
                      width: 200,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                              colors: [circlePurpleLight, circlePurpleDark]
                          )
                      ),
                    )
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      // child: GlassMorphismContainer(
                      //     height: 60,
                      //     width: 60,
                      //     borderRadius: 25,
                      //     // child: Icon(
                      //     //   Icons.notifications, color: Colors.white,
                      //     // )
                      // ),
                    ),
                    GlassMorphismContainer(
                        height: Get.height * 0.75,
                        width: Get.width* 0.8,
                        borderRadius: 20,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 24.0),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Spacer(),
                              Text(
                                "Complaint Form",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 35,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.white
                                ),
                              ),
                              Spacer(),
                              Container(
                                //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 14),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2)
                                ),
                                child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                  //hint: Text("Victim"),
                                  isExpanded: true,
                                  iconSize: 36,
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down, color: Colors.white,),
                                  items: names.map((String magac) {
                                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                      value: magac,
                                      child: Text(magac,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          color: Colors.white
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  }).toList(),
                                  onChanged: (String? val){
                                    setState(() {
                                      text = "${val}";
                                      dir(context);
                                    });
                                   // dir(context);
                                  },
                                 value: text,
                                ),
                              ),
                              // Text(text),
                             const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2)
                                ),
                                child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                  isExpanded: true,
                                  hint: Text("Acussed"),
                                  iconSize: 36,
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down, color: Colors.white,),
                                  items: names2.map((String magac2) {
                                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                      value: magac2,
                                      child: Text(magac2,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 15,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: Colors.white
                                      ),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  }).toList(),
                                  onChanged: (String? val2){
                                    setState(() {
                                      text2 = "${val2}";
                                      dir2(context);
                                    });
                                  //  print(text2);
                                  },
                                 value: text2
                                ),
                              ),
                             //Text(text),
                              SizedBox(height: 7,),
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2)
                                ),
                                child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                  isExpanded: true,
                                  hint: Text("Withness"),
                                  iconSize: 36,
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down, color: Colors.white,),
                                  items: names3.map((String magac3) {
                                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                      value: magac3,
                                      child: Text(magac3,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: Colors.white
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  }).toList(),
                                  onChanged: (String? val3){
                                    setState(() {
                                      text3 = "${val3}";
                                      dir3(context);
                                    });
                                    //await dir3(context);
                                  },
                                 value: text3,
                                ),
                              ),
                             //Text(text),
                              SizedBox(height: 7,),
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2)
                                ),
                                child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                  isExpanded: true,
                                  hint: Text("Crime"),
                                  iconSize: 36,
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down, color: Colors.white,),
                                  items: names4.map((String magac4) {
                                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                      value: magac4,
                                      child: Text(magac4,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: Colors.white
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  }).toList(),
                                  onChanged: (String? val4){
                                    setState(() {
                                      text4 = "${val4}";
                                      dir4(context);

                                    });
                                    //await dir4(context);
                                  },
                                 value: text4,
                                ),
                              ),
                             //Text(text),
                              SizedBox(height: 7,),
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2)
                                ),
                                child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                  isExpanded: true,
                                  hint: Text("Address"),
                                  iconSize: 36,
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down, color: Colors.white,),
                                  items: names1.map((String magac1) {
                                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                      value: magac1,
                                      child: Text(magac1,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: Colors.white
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  }).toList(),
                                  onChanged: (String? val1){
                                    setState(() {
                                      text1 = "${val1}";
                                      dir1(context);

                                    });
                                   //await dir1(context);
                                  },
                                   value: text1,
                                ),
                              ),
                             // Text(text1),
                              // CustomTextFiled9(
                              //   prefixIcon: Icons.people_alt_rounded,
                              //   hindText: "Name of the Withness",
                              //   suffixIcon: Icons.remove_red_eye,
                              // ),
                              //SizedBox(height: 7,),
                              // CustomTextFiled10(
                              //   prefixIcon: Icons.event,
                              //   hindText: "Type Of Crime",
                              //   suffixIcon: Icons.remove_red_eye,
                              // ),
                              // SizedBox(height: 7,),
                              SizedBox(height: 7,),
                              CustomTextFiled11(
                                prefixIcon: Icons.date_range_rounded,
                                hindText: "Date",
                                suffixIcon: Icons.remove_red_eye,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 7,),
                              CustomTextFiled12(
                                prefixIcon: Icons.description,
                                hindText: "Description",
                                suffixIcon: Icons.remove_red_eye,
                              ),
                              // SizedBox(height: 7,),
                              // CustomTextFiled13(
                              //   prefixIcon: Icons.verified_user,
                              //   hindText: "User Id",
                              //   suffixIcon: Icons.remove_red_eye,
                              // ),
                              // SizedBox(height: 7,),
                              Container(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                                child: RaisedButton(
                                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    dir(context);
                                    dir1(context);
                                    dir2(context);
                                    dir3(context);
                                    dir4(context);
                                    complaint(context);
                                  },
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(26),
                                  ),
                                  child: Text("Submit",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: Colors.white
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              // GestureDetector(
                              //   onTap: () => Get.to(() => SignInPage()) ,
                              //   child: Container(
                              //     alignment: Alignment.center,
                              //     child: Container(
                              //       padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              //         horizontal: 16.0,
                              //       ),
                              //       height: 50.0,
                              //       width: 200,
                              //       alignment: Alignment.center,
                              //       decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              //         border: Border.all(
                              //           width: 2.0,
                              //           color: Colors.white,
                              //         ),
                              //         borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              //           Radius.circular(30.0),
                              //         ),
                              //       ),
                              //       child: Text("Submit",
                              //         style: TextStyle(
                              //             color: Colors.white,
                              //             fontSize: 20
                              //         ),
                              //       ),
                              //     ),
                              //   ),
                              // ),
                              Spacer(),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                    ),
                    Spacer(),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: GlassMorphismContainer(
                        height: 50.0,
                        width: Get.width * 0.80,
                        borderRadius: 10,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text("Please Don't submit what didn't even happen",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 16
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),

                      ),
                    ),
                    Spacer(),
                  ],
                )
              ],

            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future dir(BuildContext context) async {
 try{
   var ul = "http://192.168.242.149:81/combo.php";
   http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ul), body:'');
   var xog = jsonDecode(response.body);
   if (bol) {
     for (int i = 0; i < xog.length; i++) {
       var xy = xog[i].values.toList();
       names.add(xy[0]);
     }
     bol = false;
   }
 }catch(e){
   print('Meshaan Lagaa heystaa: $e');
 }
}

Future dir1(BuildContext context) async {
  try{
    var ul1 = "http://192.168.242.149:81/comboadd.php";
    http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ul1), body: '');
    var xog1 = jsonDecode(response.body);
    if (bol1) {
      for (int i = 0; i < xog1.length; i++) {
        var xy1 = xog1[i].values.toList();
        names1.add(xy1[0]);
      }
      bol1 = false;
    }
  }catch(e){
    print('Meshaan Lagaa heystaa: $e');
  }
}

Future dir2(BuildContext context) async {
  try{
    var ul2 = "http://192.168.242.149:81/comboac.php";
    http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ul2), body: '');
    var xog2 = jsonDecode(response.body);
    if (bol2) {
      for (int i = 0; i < xog2.length; i++) {
        var xy2 = xog2[i].values.toList();
        names2.add(xy2[0]);
      }
      bol2 = false;
    }
  }catch(e){
    print('Meshaan Lagaa heystaa: $e');
  }
}


Future dir3(BuildContext context) async {
  try{
    var ul3 = "http://192.168.242.149:81/combowh.php";
    http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ul3), body: '');
    var xog3 = jsonDecode(response.body);
    if (bol3) {
      for (int i = 0; i < xog3.length; i++) {
        var xy3 = xog3[i].values.toList();
        names3.add(xy3[0]);
      }
      bol3 = false;
    }
  }catch(e){
    print('Meshaan Lagaa heystaa: $e');
  }
}


Future dir4(BuildContext context) async {
  try{
    var ul4 = "http://192.168.242.149:81/combocr.php";
    http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ul4), body: '');
    var xog4 = jsonDecode(response.body);
    if (bol4) {
      for (int i = 0; i < xog4.length; i++) {
        var xy4 = xog4[i].values.toList();
        names4.add(xy4[0]);
      }
      bol4 = false;
    }
  }catch(e){
    print('Meshaan Lagaa heystaa: $e');
  }
}


Future complaint(context) async{
  try{
    Map xog = {'txtvc':text, 'txtac':text2,
      'txtwh':text3, 'txtcr':text4, 'txtad':text1,
      'txtdt':dt.text, 'txtdes':des.text, 'txtuserid':user
    };
    //String data = json.encode(xog);
    http.Response res = await http.post(Uri.parse("http://192.168.242.149:81/complaint.php"), body: xog);

   //  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(res.body)));
      var data1= json.decode(json.encode(res.body));
    if(data1 == "success"){
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: Text(res.body)));
      print(res.body);
      // Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>NewHome()));
    }
    else{
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(res.body)));
    }
  }catch(e){
    print('Meshaan Lagaa heystaa: $e');
  }

}
```

this problem coz of 'txtvc':text this "text" is the value of the first drop down button and it can't be converted to text or string

and my php code:

```
<?php
$victim=$_REQUEST['txtvc'];
$acussed=$_REQUEST['txtac'];
$withness=$_REQUEST['txtwh'];
$cr_no=$_REQUEST['txtcr'];
$add_no=$_REQUEST['txtad'];
// $c_date=$_REQUEST['txtdt'];
$description=$_REQUEST['txtdes'];
$user_id=$_REQUEST['txtuserid'];
//$deleted=$_REQUEST['txtcdel'];
$date=date("Y/m/d");
$db=new mysqli("localhost","root","","app");
$sql="insert into complaint values(null,'$victim', '$acussed','$withness','$cr_no','$add_no',curdate(),'$description','$user_id','0')";
$natiijo=$db->query($sql)==1?"success":"failed";
echo json_encode($natiijo);
?>
```

so please help me out my supervisor is waiting

Answer (score -1):

isolate what's causing the issue

make sure the backend is working correctly first before passing information to it from the front end, change 'test text' to an alternative data type as appropriate for your db structure

go to your browser and open URL http://192.168.242.149:81/combo.php

if the backend is working correctly the below data should be added to your db, if not then you need to fix the backend

```
    <?php
    $victim= 'test text';
    $acussed= 'test text';
    $withness= 'test text';
    $cr_no= 'test text';
    $add_no= 'test text';
    $description= 'test text';
    $user_id= 'test text';
    $date=date("Y/m/d");
    $db=new mysqli("localhost","root","","app");
    $sql="insert into complaint values(null,'$victim','$acussed','$withness','$cr_no','$add_no',curdate(),'$description','$user_id','0')";
    ?>
```

Comment: The problem isn't from the back end it is from the front end specially drop down button